# Adding mysql entries together and displaying them in a table

Tags: php, mysql, select

My data (simplified) looks like....

```
------------------------
| key |  id  | minspld |
------------------------
| 1   | 400  |   90    |
| 2   | 400  |   40    |
| 3   | 401  |   38    |
| 4   | 401  |   90    |
| 5   | 402  |   90    |
| 6   | 402  |   89    |
| 7   | 403  |   77    |
| 8   | 403  |   15    |
| 9   | 404  |   90    |
-----------------------
```

I am trying to do....

- For each `id`, add all their `minspld` entries together
- Display them in a table like above, but each `id` only showing once, and the minspld column showing the total per each id.

Here's what I'm using at the moment and I'm displaying all entries separately (eg, each person shows twice)

```
<table><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Mins Played</th></tr></thead>
<tbody>

<?php
$queryget = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM mlsstats ORDER BY id ASC") or die(mysql_error());

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($queryget))
{
    $id = $row['id'];
    $minspld = $row['minspld'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$id."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$minspld."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>

</tbody></table>
```

How would I write this to make each id show only once in the HTML, but with the added totals of all their `minspld` entries? (eg, id 400 would have 130. id 401 would have 128. etc.)

If this isn't clear, please let me know.. and thanks for any help.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try changing your query to:

```
SELECT id, SUM(minspld) AS minspld FROM mlsstats GROUP BY id ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: PERFECT! Thanks so much. I knew there'd be an easy way to do it, but it kept failing no matter what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to use a loop for this. You can simply do this with query
Just run the query and get two columns. id and its total

```
SELECT
    m.id,
    SUM(minspld) AS TCount
FROM mytable AS m
GROUP BY m.id
```

Comment: Yeah that's why I asked here.. because I could only do it by stupid loops and I knew there'd be an easy way. I have it working now using the single select statement. Thanks!